# GetService<IMultisiteContext>() throwing error

Tags: sxa

While using `GetService<IMultisiteContext>()`, this error is occurring: `The non-generic method IServiceProvider.GetService(Type) cannot be used with Type arguments.`

Code Snippet used:

```
var contextItem = Context.Item;
var siteItem = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMultisiteContext>().GetSiteItem(contextItem);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you referenced `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`:

[image]

Then add using:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

That library contains generic extension for non-generic `GetService` method.

Comment: Hi Marek, I am already using `Sitecore.DependencyInjection`. Is it good?

Comment: It's not enough. You have to add a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` as well

Comment: Keep in mind, this site is not an interactive debugging service.

Comment: VS Quick Actions not always handle extensions method well. Make sure you referenced the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library (the same version which is used by your Sitecore instance) and that you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` statement in your file. It will work